# Add package name to symbol

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

This is a general symbol question in a specific context.  The question I think I need to answer is: given a parameter containing a symbol 'foo, how do I manipulate the package part of the symbol so that it is eql to 'package:foo?

The more specific context:  There is a unit-testing package, fiveam, that stores test functions in a hash table (`it.bese.fiveam::*tests`) with keys like `package::test-name` that hash to an object containing the tests.  To run a test, one normally passes to the `run!` function a symbol that is a hash key:  `(run! 'package::test-name`.  If I'm calling `run!` from the `tests` package in which I defined the tests, I can just C-x C-e on `(run! 'test-name)`.  When calling from the SLIME REPL, I have to do `(tests::run! 'tests::test-name)`, which is a mild inconvenience.

I'd like to run tests from cl-user with `(run! 'test-name)` and omit the package name.  I thought it would be simple to wrap `run!` and add the missing package to the symbol, but all my tries fail, I guess in part because `CL-USER:test-name` is a different thing from `tests:test-name`.

The hash table in question uses `eql` to test equality.  In the `tests` package:

```
(eql 'tests::foo 'foo) => T
```

In CL-USER:

```
(eql 'tests::foo 'foo) => nil
```

Various functions can return symbols (e.g. intern, make-symbol or format-symbol) but none of them are eql to the keys in the hash table:

```
(eql (alexandria:format-symbol t "foo::bar") 'foo::bar) => nil
(eql (make-symbol "foo::bar") 'foo::bar) => nil
```

Taking this out of the SLIME/REPL/FIVEAM context to generalize where I think the problem is, I can't figure out how to take `'bar` and turn it into `'foo:bar` as a symbol.  I can specify it manually as `'foo:bar`, but I can't seem to get anything to eql `'foo:bar`, given `'bar`.

Note: I don't really care about typing the extra few letters for a package name.  What I'm really trying to do here is improve my understanding of scoping and specifying symbols.

Thank you.

Comment: `(find-symbol (symbol-name 'bar) :foo)` will return the symbol named `BAR` in the package named `FOO` if such a symbol is interned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I assume, that you know, that you can switch to the `test` package in the SLIME REPL using the extended command `in-package` (i.e., at the REPL prompt, type a comma `,` followed by `in-package`, you will be prompted for a package name), and that switching packages like that is simply inconvenient for you.

One solution could be to introduce a little helper function in whatever package you are currently working in:

```
(defun run-test (name &optional (package 'test))
   (funcall (find-symbol #.(symbol-name 'run!) package)
            (find-symbol (symbol-name name) package)))
```

or simpler (and assuming, that the definition of `run!` came from the fiveam package via `:use` or `:import` into the `test` package)

```
(defun run-test (name &optional (package 'test))
   (it.bese.fiveam:run! (find-symbol (symbol-name name) package)))
```

which you can now call as

```
(run-test 'check-everything)
```

Note, that we use `find-symbol` here instead of `intern`, since we expect the symbols to exist in all cases. If you want the helper to be easily accessible everywhere, you can even do

```
(defun :run (name &optional (package 'test))
   (it.bese.fiveam:run! (find-symbol (symbol-name name) package)))
```

and now you can call it as

```
(:run 'check-everything)
```

in regardless of the current package. Note, that I would recommend this only for helpers intended to be used in the REPL. Clobbering a global namespace (like the keyword function namespace) like that looks a little fishy to me.

Just for good measure: none of the code given has been tested (or even passed through a REPL) so beware. Also, I heartily recommend reading the [chapter on packages and symbols](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/11_aab.htm) in the CLHS, which should be considered The Ultimate Source™ for these things.

Comment: This smoothed out some of my thinking.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function [`import`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_import.htm#import) to import the symbols you want:

```
(import '(fiveam:run! my-tests::foo))
```

This imports both symbols into your *current package* (you can also give a different package as another argument).  You can then

```
(run! 'foo)
```

If you try this import after some of your failed attempts, you might land in the debugger, where you can select the appropriate restart to resolve the conflict between symbols of the same name (something like “TAKE NEW”).